# how can i use apply directive in tailwindcss when i am using CDN?

Tags: tailwind-css

`I Tried to use apply directive of tailwind css, but it's not working.

I expected that apply will work without config.js file...right now , i am using cdn.
here is my html code:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<button type = "button" class ="mx-12 my-12 rounded-xl bg-blue-400 hover:bg-yellow-500 active:bg-yellow-200 p-10">Click me</button>
<button type="button" class = "btnhello">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

`styles.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer components {
    .btnhello{
    @apply mx-12 my-12 rounded-xl bg-yellow-400 hover:bg-yellow-500 active:bg-yellow-200 p-10;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Community

Answer (score 2):

You can use `type="text/tailwindcss"` to add custom CSS that supports **all of Tailwind's CSS features**.
Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <style type="text/tailwindcss">
      @layer components {
        .btn {
          @apply mx-12 my-12 rounded-xl bg-blue-400 hover:bg-yellow-500 active:bg-yellow-200 p-10;
        }
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class ="btn">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn

Answer (score 1):

Currently There is no way of using `@apply` directive with TailwindCSS CDN. Because, It's a feature which can be used along only with `postcss` library. When You're using CDN, It doesn't include `postcss`.